# Loading and saving JSON files in a GWT web application

Tags: ajax, json, gwt

We are developing an GWT web-application with an Python webapp2 webserver. At this point we want to load and save files within the web-application. We cannot use Flash for this task.

Saving

The current approach is to use a form upload using the target "_blank" and set the correct MIME to make the browser download the file. This solution works, but since the webapp2 webserver does not support streaming (thus the mime type cannot be validated by the browser in a short time), a new browser-window is opened each time. Is there a better solution e.g. using iFrames?

Loading

Again using form upload and parsing the response (JSON). We use the content-type "text/html; charset=UTF-8". This solution works perfectly in IE9 but does not work in Chrome and FireFox. It seems, that the JSON response gets corrupted in some way or is there anything from when parsing a JSON response from a form upload response? We use piriti for JSON (de)serialization.

Answer (score 0):

For loading, you can use [RestyGWT](http://restygwt.fusesource.org/index.html) library, it has capability encoding or decoding Java Object to JSON:

```
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
...
public interface PizzaOrderCodec extends JsonEncoderDecoder<PizzaOrder> {
}

// GWT will implement the interface for you
PizzaOrderCodec codec = GWT.create(PizzaOrderCodec.class);

// Encoding an object to json
PizzaOrder order = ... 
JSONValue json = codec.encode(order);

// decoding an object to from json
PizzaOrder other = codec.decode(json);
```

For saving, if you have to send JSON file using file upload, you can see following link:
http://www.jroller.com/hasant/entry/fileupload_with_gwt

http://www.celinio.net/techblog/?p=1207

Have a nice time.